# How often should postgres full text search column be reindexed?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Postgres Full-text search (tsvector) for search. Also, I am using below query to update indexes every time after each insert/update.

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET tsv = setweight(to_tsvector(name), 'A');
```

Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in a trigger function and call that on insert/update.

Comment: the most efficient would be populating it as part of insert/update statement